# Using linq to calculate rating average in EF Core

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asp.net-core, query-optimization

The user can search for companies by city, brand, service type and rating. I have developed such a query, but I am getting an error in the rating section. The error message is as follows:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Join(
> outer: DbSet,
> inner: f => f.Id,
> outerKeySelector: c => c.FirmId,
> innerKeySelector: (f, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<Firm, Comment>(
> outer = f,
> inner = c
> ))
> .GroupBy(
> source: ti => ti.Outer,
> keySelector: ti => new {
> firm = ti.Outer,
> rating = ti.Inner.Rate
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
> ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I encountered this error after adding the rating part. How can I fix this? I don't think it will be effective to pull the data in this way. How should I go about developing this place? I also share the codes I used for the query with you.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Firm>> GetFirmsForCustomerSearch(int cityId, int brandId, int serviceTypeId, int rate)
        {
           var query = from firms in AracsalContext.Firm select firms;
            
            if (brandId > 0)
                query = from firms in query
                        join firmBrands in AracsalContext.Firmbrand on new { f1 = firms.Id, f2 = brandId } equals new { f1 = firmBrands.FirmId, f2 = firmBrands.BrandId }
                        select firms;

            if (serviceTypeId > 0)
                query = from firms in query
                        join firmServices in AracsalContext.Firmservice on new { f1 = firms.Id, f2 = serviceTypeId } equals new { f1 = firmServices.FirmId, f2 = firmServices.ServiceId }
                        select firms;

            if (cityId > 0)
                query = from firms in query
                        where firms.CityId == cityId
                        select firms;

            if (rate > 0)
            {
                query = from firms in query
                        join comments in AracsalContext.Comment on firms.Id equals comments.FirmId
                        group new
                        {
                            firm = firms,
                            rating = comments.Rate
                        } by firms into g
                        where g.Average(r => r.rating) > rate
                        select g.Key;
            }


            var result = await query.ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }
```

Thank you so much.
Ramazan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping in SQL has limitations - you can return only grouping key and aggregation result. For returning whole record, you have to join to original query gain.

```cs
if (rate > 0)
{
    filteredByRate = 
        from firms in query
        join comments in AracsalContext.Comment on firms.Id equals comments.FirmId
        group new
        {
            rating = comments.Rate
        } by new { firms.Id } into g
        where g.Average(r => r.rating) > rate
        select g.Key;

    query = 
        from films in query
        join f in filteredByRate on films.Id equals f.Id
        select films;
}
```

Comment: In the error message, it said that there may be a limit problem. I think you are right. Also your suggestion fixed the problem, thank you. So is there a way to aggregate these joins in a single query? Would doing it this way cause a performance issue?

Comment: It should be no performance issues and it is a normal way to decompose query in small understandable parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by some Id like firms.Id

```
query = from firms in query
                        join comments in AracsalContext.Comment on firms.Id equals comments.FirmId
                        group new
                        {
                            firm = firms,
                            rating = comments.Rate
                        } by firms.Id into g
                        where g.Average(r => r.rating) > rate
                        select g.Key;
```

Comment: When I do this, the return value is int. Whereas I want the return value to be firm. That's why I did it like this